# How to record actions with timings?

Tags: intellij-idea

Macros are useless to myself, they don't record timings , if I do action A and then action B after 10 seconds, IntelliJ (ver. 15) simply plays all of them simultaneously. Frustratingly useless teasing feature which could be so useful. Is there an alternative?

Scenario is simple:

In embedded application with tomcat(spring boot) we execute 'gulp build' (frontend build tool) which builds files to 'resources/static' folder, since the applciation is .jar we need to reload changed resources via HotSwap.

```
---> 'gulp build' ---------- wait 10 seconds ------------> alt+u; alt+a; ('Reload changed classes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros don't record timings because they're intended for automating editor operations, and users usually expect these operations to be performed as quickly as possible, and not to sit through the delays that they originally made while they were recording the action.

The best way to accomplish your task would be to write a small plugin that would run the 'gulp build' process, wait for it to complete (rather than waiting a hard-coded number of seconds), and then reload the changed classes.

Comment: One way or another I am left in position where I have to manually do these voodoo operations. Will see if I can auto-rebuild for gulp file changes. IntelliJ plugin demo page leaves impression to me that it will take whole day to write such plugin.